# How can I create a base TypeScript type that can be extended by other types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to use a third party TypeScript module and am having trouble creating an abstract type that other types can extend.

The base type Animal will be either Mammal, Reptile, or Amphibian.

The `action` method from a third party `ActionModule` will take a slightly different type as input for each action, but I wanted to create a base type that can be given for the generic `U` from `ActionModule` for my `ACTIONS` type.

Here's what I have so far, which doesn't seem to work (getting an error saying types are incompatible).

```
type Animal = Mammal | Reptile | Amphibian;

type Mammal = {
  name: string,
  furColor: number
};

type Reptile = {
  name: string,
  scaleCount: number
};

type Amphibian = {
  name: string;
};

// Third-party module
interface ActionModule<T = {}, U = {}> {
  description: string,
  action: (args: Arguments<U>) => void
}

const ACTIONS: {
  [key: string]: ActionModule<{}, Animal>
} = {
  actionOne: {
      description: '',
      action: (args: Arguments<Mammal>) => {},
    },
  actionTwo: {
    description: '',
    action: (args: Arguments<Reptile>) => {},
  },
  actionThree: {
    description: '',
    action: (args: Arguments<Amphibian>) => {},
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example, there is no `Arguments` type

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

```
type Animal = Mammal & Reptile & Amphibian
```

Longer answer:

Expanding and simplyfying your code we get:

```
action: (args: Mammal | Reptile | Amphibian) => void
```

Which means that the argument of this function can take any of the types specified in the union. So to **each** implementation of the interface **must support all the union types**.

Instead you can **merge the interfaces** which means that the method **may support one of the types**. More specificlly it will allow an object that has at least common properties of the interfaces.